# How to apply dependent price combination in product custom options dependency with Main price in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options, price-rules

[image]
 - Product is eligible for **purchase** and **lease**
 - purchase price is 240
 - lease price is 24 per month (240 for 240 months)

**1. How to make price dependent with this custom option with main price**

ex.

1. If Option is **purchase** then price will be **240**
2. If option will be **lease** the price will be **Main price/Rental Term**

---

**2. How to make combination price for Rental Term and Service (Both are product custom option)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to purchase the dependent custom option extension Or create the custom module.
Link for extension,

1. https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/dependent-custom-options-for-magento-2.html
2. https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-dependent-custom-options-extension.html
3. https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-advanced-product-options-suite.html (Recommended)..

If you want to create the custom functionality for set the custom price based on the selection then you must need to set the price using the observer.

> I don't have checked this code works or not but you can use the
>   logic.Please don't use object manager as well.You need to create the
>   block file to get the product collection.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$values = array();
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
           $p = $o->getValues();
        }
    }
  foreach($p as $v)
        {
            $values[$v->getId()]['option_type_id']= $v->getId();
                $values[$v->getId()]['title']= 'test';
                $values[$v->getId()]['price']= 23;
                $values[$v->getId()]['price_type']= 'fixed';
                $values[$v->getId()]['sku']= $value1;

          }
        $v->setValues($values);
        $v->saveValues();
$product->save();
```

Comment: I want to create custom module, any suggestion for that ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the efforts :) i will check it and update you soon!!!

Answer (score -1):

Custom options are one of the inseparable parts of a product in Magento. Store owners often need to offer custom options dependent on each other. For ex., you need to show 'Green' color only when the size 'Large' is selected.

I recommend [Dependant custom option Magento Extension](https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/dependent-custom-options-for-magento-2.html) to you. This extension facilitates admin to show or hide the custom options based on a selection of the parent custom options. Admin can quickly set the dependency relation between the custom options. Admin can select which custom option will behave as a parent and which as a child.

I hope this will help.